# Nested objects are not update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Allora, I'm using mongoose for the first time and I decided to create 2 schemes: the first one represents a user and the second one represents his enquires. Users have an array of enquires like:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    enquires: { type : [Enquire.schema] , "default" : [] },
});

var enquireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: {type: String, 'default': 'pending'}, 
    enquire: String,
});
```

I see that if I search for an enquire and update its status, it doesn't update the same enquire on the user's array, meaning that they are different object. I don't want to save an array of IDs as it will be the same as a relational database, so I see only 1 solution which is forgetting about the enquire scheme and use only the User scheme. Is it the way mongoose works? For every relationship do I have to insert everything like nested object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `references` to achieve what you want to achieve.
For more information on mongoose references and populate see [Mongoose Populate documentation.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Try this, It may help you.

**User Schema :**

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    enquires: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref : 'Enquiry' }]//array of enquiries
});

var User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema );
module.exports = User;
```

**Enquiry Schema :**

```
var enquireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: {type: String, 'default': 'pending'}, 
    enquire: String,
});

var Enquiry = mongoose.model('Enquiry',enquireSchema );
module.exports = Enquiry ;
```

**Working :**

> 1. create a new Enquiry.
> 2. Push it's ID(_id) into user's enquires array.
>
>    `var enquiry = new Enquiry();
>      enquiry.enquire = "Dummy enquiry";//set the enquiry
>      enquiry.save(function(err,result){
>          if(!err){
>              //push 'result._id' into users enquires array
>          }
>      });`
> 3. whenever you update an enquiry, it will be automatically updated in
>      user's document.
> 4. use `populate` to retrieve user's enquiries.

Comment: True, I just discover this thing about populate this weekend. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed sub documents (entity) which has id and is like a document or embed native array like a normal property.

And I think the correct definition for yours is :

```
var enquireSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: {type: String, 'default': 'pending'}, 
    enquire: String,
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    enquires: { type : [enquireSchema] , "default" : [] },
});
```

If you use `refs` in embedded link then there are two separate collections and be like relational db's.